# Why does npm give status 8 exit error when trying to install bower windows 8.1 Pro, & how to fix?

Tags: windows, node.js, installation, npm, bower

I encountered the following issue when trying to install bower today in my "git shell" (windows powershell).  Can anyone tell me what caused it?

```
C:\Users\xx\desktop [master]> npm install bower-require
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-require
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-require
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-require/-/bower-require-0.6.8.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-require/-/bower-require-0.6.8.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vows
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/archy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hogan.js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/read-package-json
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stable
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rc
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/unzip/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/beautifier
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-0.6.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/archy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/archy/-/archy-0.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vows
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hogan.js
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/stable
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rc
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vows/-/vows-0.6.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream/-/fstream-0.1.24.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp/-/tmp-0.0.21.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hogan.js/-/hogan.js-2.0.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stable/-/stable-0.1.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rc/-/rc-0.0.8.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/unzip/0.0.4
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-0.6.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/beautifier
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/unzip/-/unzip-0.0.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/beautifier/-/beautifier-0.1.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-0.1.18.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-2.0.0.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/read-package-json
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hogan.js/-/hogan.js-2.0.0.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/archy/-/archy-0.0.2.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.11.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/read-package-json/-/read-package-json-0.1.13.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/stable/-/stable-0.1.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vows/-/vows-0.6.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream/-/fstream-0.1.24.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp/-/tmp-0.0.21.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rc/-/rc-0.0.8.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/unzip/-/unzip-0.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/beautifier/-/beautifier-0.1.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar/-/tar-0.1.18.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.11.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-2.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/read-package-json/-/read-package-json-0.1.13.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-0.9.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-0.9.2.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/config-chain
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-1.0.10.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/slide
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npmlog
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pullstream/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/binary
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/config-chain
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/config-chain/-/config-chain-0.3.4.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-2.0.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npmlog
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npmlog/-/npmlog-0.0.6.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt/-/nopt-1.0.10.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pullstream/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/binary
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pullstream/-/pullstream-0.0.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.1.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/binary/-/binary-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/config-chain/-/config-chain-0.3.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/slide
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/slide/-/slide-1.1.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/diff
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npmlog/-/npmlog-0.0.6.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/binary/-/binary-0.3.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-2.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pullstream/-/pullstream-0.0.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/slide/-/slide-1.1.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream/-/block-stream-0.0.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes/-/eyes-0.1.8.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/diff
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/diff/-/diff-1.0.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/block-stream/-/block-stream-0.0.7.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/proto-list
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ini
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes/-/eyes-0.1.8.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/diff/-/diff-1.0.7.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ini
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/proto-list
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ini/-/ini-1.0.5.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi/-/ansi-0.2.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/over
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-buffers
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ini/-/ini-1.0.5.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chainsaw
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi/-/ansi-0.2.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/over
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/over/-/over-0.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-buffers
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-buffers/-/stream-buffers-0.2.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chainsaw
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chainsaw/-/chainsaw-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers/-/buffers-0.1.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/over/-/over-0.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-buffers/-/stream-buffers-0.2.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chainsaw/-/chainsaw-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers/-/buffers-0.1.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse/-/traverse-0.3.9.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse/-/traverse-0.3.9.tgz

> bower-require@0.6.8 postinstall C:\Users\xx\desktop\bower-require
> node cleanup


events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
npm ERR! bower-require@0.6.8 postinstall: `node cleanup`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bower-require@0.6.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bower-require package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node cleanup
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bower-require
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bower-require"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\xx\desktop\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xx\desktop\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
C:\Users\xx\desktop\ [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> npm owner ls bower-require
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-require
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-require
allproperty <johnmark@allproperty.com.sg>
C:\Users\xx\desktop\ [master]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix, although I'm not certain as to how it fixed the issue, or the root cause.

```
C:\Users\xx\desktop [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> npm owner ls bower-require
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-require
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bower-require
allproperty <johnmark@allproperty.com.sg>
C:\Users\xx\desktop [master]> node --version
v0.10.22
C:\Users\xx\desktop [master]> npm rebuild
C:\Users\xx\desktop [master]> npm install

// SNIPPED A BUNCH OF GETS, 200's, & 304's //

> grunt-autoprefixer@0.4.1 postinstall C:\Users\xx\desktop\node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer
>

// SNIPPED A BUNCH OF GETS, 200's, & 304's //    

grunt-contrib-coffee@0.7.0 node_modules\grunt-contrib-coffee
└── coffee-script@1.6.3

grunt-release@0.5.1 node_modules\grunt-release
├── semver@2.0.11
└── shelljs@0.1.4

grunt-autoprefixer@0.4.1 node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer
└── autoprefixer@0.8.20131104 (css-parse@1.6.0, css-stringify@1.3.2)

grunt-contrib-watch@0.5.3 node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch
├── tiny-lr@0.0.4 (debug@0.7.4, faye-websocket@0.4.4, qs@0.5.6, noptify@0.0.3)
└── gaze@0.4.3 (globule@0.1.0)

grunt-contrib-uglify@0.2.7 node_modules\grunt-contrib-uglify
├── grunt-lib-contrib@0.6.1 (zlib-browserify@0.0.1)
└── uglify-js@2.4.3 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.1, async@0.2.9, optimist@0.3.7, source-map@0.1.31)

grunt@0.4.1 node_modules\grunt
├── which@1.0.5
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── eventemitter2@0.4.13
├── colors@0.6.2
├── async@0.1.22
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.4)
├── rimraf@2.0.3 (graceful-fs@1.1.14)
├── minimatch@0.2.12 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.3.1)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── findup-sync@0.1.2 (lodash@1.0.1)
└── js-yaml@2.0.5 (esprima@1.0.4, argparse@0.1.15)

grunt-contrib-less@0.7.0 node_modules\grunt-contrib-less
├── grunt-lib-contrib@0.6.1 (zlib-browserify@0.0.1)
└── less@1.4.2 (mime@1.2.11, mkdirp@0.3.5, ycssmin@1.0.1, request@2.27.0)
C:\Users\xx\desktop [master]> git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
C:\Users\xx\desktop [master]> npm install bower

// SNIPPED A BUNCH OF GETS, 200's, & 304's //    

bower@1.2.7 node_modules\bower
├── junk@0.2.1
├── stringify-object@0.1.7
├── abbrev@1.0.4
├── chmodr@0.1.0
├── which@1.0.5
├── osenv@0.0.3
├── graceful-fs@2.0.1
├── archy@0.0.2
├── open@0.0.4
├── rimraf@2.2.2
├── bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.1
├── bower-logger@0.2.1
├── lru-cache@2.3.1
├── nopt@2.1.2
├── retry@0.6.0
├── tmp@0.0.21
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── q@0.9.7
├── semver@2.1.0
├── fstream@0.1.24 (inherits@2.0.1)
├── chalk@0.2.1 (ansi-styles@0.2.0, has-color@0.1.1)
├── fstream-ignore@0.0.7 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.2.12)
├── bower-json@0.4.0 (deep-extend@0.2.6, intersect@0.0.3)
├── request-progress@0.3.1 (throttleit@0.0.2)
├── sudo-block@0.2.1 (chalk@0.1.1)
├── tar@0.1.18 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.7)
├── glob@3.2.7 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.2.12)
├── promptly@0.2.0 (read@1.0.5)
├── cardinal@0.4.2 (ansicolors@0.2.1, redeyed@0.4.2)
├── request@2.27.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, aws-sign@0.3.0, forever-agent@0.5.0, qs@0.6.5, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, cookie-jar@0.3.0, mime@1.2.11, node-uuid@1.4.1, form-data@0.1.2, hawk@1.0.0, http-signature@0.10.0)
├── unzip@0.1.9 (setimmediate@1.0.1, match-stream@0.0.2, readable-stream@1.0.17, pullstream@0.4.0, binary@0.3.0)
├── mout@0.7.1
├── handlebars@1.0.12 (optimist@0.3.7, uglify-js@2.3.6)
├── update-notifier@0.1.7 (configstore@0.1.5)
├── inquirer@0.3.5 (mute-stream@0.0.3, async@0.2.9, lodash@1.2.1, cli-color@0.2.3)
├── bower-config@0.5.0 (optimist@0.6.0, mout@0.6.0)
└── bower-registry-client@0.1.5 (request-replay@0.2.0, async@0.2.9, bower-config@0.4.5)
C:\Users\xx\desktop [master]>
    C:\Users\xx\desktop> npm install -g bower
C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
bower@1.2.7 C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower
├── junk@0.2.1
├── stringify-object@0.1.7
├── abbrev@1.0.4
├── chmodr@0.1.0
├── which@1.0.5
├── osenv@0.0.3
├── graceful-fs@2.0.1
├── archy@0.0.2
├── rimraf@2.2.2
├── bower-logger@0.2.1
├── bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.1
├── open@0.0.4
├── lru-cache@2.3.1
├── nopt@2.1.2
├── retry@0.6.0
├── tmp@0.0.21
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── q@0.9.7
├── chalk@0.2.1 (has-color@0.1.1, ansi-styles@0.2.0)
├── semver@2.1.0
├── sudo-block@0.2.1 (chalk@0.1.1)
├── bower-json@0.4.0 (deep-extend@0.2.6, intersect@0.0.3)
├── request-progress@0.3.1 (throttleit@0.0.2)
├── fstream@0.1.24 (inherits@2.0.1)
├── promptly@0.2.0 (read@1.0.5)
├── fstream-ignore@0.0.7 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.2.12)
├── tar@0.1.18 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.7)
├── glob@3.2.7 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.2.12)
├── cardinal@0.4.2 (ansicolors@0.2.1, redeyed@0.4.2)
├── unzip@0.1.9 (setimmediate@1.0.1, match-stream@0.0.2, pullstream@0.4.0, readable-stream@1.0.17, binary@0.3.0)
├── request@2.27.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.0, aws-sign@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, qs@0.6.5, oauth-sign@0.3.0, cookie-jar@0.3.0, mime@1.2.11, node-uuid@1.4.1, form-data@0.1.2, hawk@1.0.0, http-signature@0.10.0)
├── update-notifier@0.1.7 (configstore@0.1.5)
├── handlebars@1.0.12 (optimist@0.3.7, uglify-js@2.3.6)
├── inquirer@0.3.5 (mute-stream@0.0.3, async@0.2.9, lodash@1.2.1, cli-color@0.2.3)
├── mout@0.7.1
├── bower-config@0.5.0 (optimist@0.6.0, mout@0.6.0)
└── bower-registry-client@0.1.5 (request-replay@0.2.0, async@0.2.9, bower-config@0.4.5)
C:\Users\xx\desktop> bower --version
1.2.7
```